# split data and generate a plot showing different counts for split data

Tags: r

I have split data based on a column. Now I want to count number of rows for each category and make a single plot.

Here is an example

```
X1 =c(1,2,3,4,10,20,22,21)
X2 =c(A,A,A,B,B,B,C,C)
data <- data.frame(cbind(X1,X2))

X1  X2
1    A
2    A
3    A
4    B
10   B
20   B
22   C
21   C

split(data,data$X2)
$A
  X1 X2
  1  A
  2  A
  3  A

$B
  X1 X2
  4  B
  10  B
  20  B

$C
  X1 X2
  22  C
  21  C
```

In my original dataset there are more than 30 categories(X2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mydf = structure(list(X1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 10L, 20L, 22L, 21L), X2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("X1", 
"X2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
> 
> 
> mydf
  X1 X2
1  1  A
2  2  A
3  3  A
4  4  B
5 10  B
6 20  B
7 22  C
8 21  C


barplot(table(mydf$X2))
```

[image]

EDIT: For larger data:

```
mydf <- data.frame(X1=sample(x=1:100, size=17000, replace=TRUE),
 X2=sample(x=LETTERS, size=17000, replace=TRUE))

barplot(table(mydf$X2))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your code but my data file has around 17000 rows and lables will be more than 30. Is there any alternative way?

Comment: It should work unless there is a memory problem. Try and post results here.

Comment: thnaks. I have used your first script for the large dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option using `dplyr` and either `ggplot2` or `ggvis` (with a fabricated data set to mimic what you have)

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggvis)
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(X1=sample(x=1:100, size=17000, replace=TRUE),
                  X2=sample(x=LETTERS, size=17000, replace=TRUE))

dat.summary <- summarise(group_by(dat, X2), count=n())

# ggplot
qplot(data=dat.summary, x=X2, y=count, geom="bar", stat="identity") + theme_bw()
```

[image]

```
# ggvis
dat.summary %>% ggvis(~X2, ~count) %>% layer_bars()
```

[image]